# Is there any way to download an entire Vbulletin forum?

Tags: download, forum, vbulletin

Is there any way to download an entire Vbulletin forum? It could just be in text files or whatever, doesn't matter to me but html files where the look of it is the same would be preferable.

I want an offline copy of the forum.

edit: the forum is password locked, I have to sign in before the forum becomes visible. So I don't think you can just target it with a script to download unless you can login first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Linux, you can do that with the `wget` tool:

```
wget --recursive http://www.websiteurl.com/
```

Some additional [examples with wget](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/).